# Django post manytomany field with form

Tags: python, django, django-1.10

I tried to select poi(point of interest) to make loi(line of interest), I met two problems on many to many fields:

1.Why I can't post the multiple selected options.

2.How to change the name in the option with the name I want (e.g. POI_title)
[original name/image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cx3c0.png)

**Model.py**

```
class POI(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    poi_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    POI_title = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{}({})".format(self.POI_date, self.user)

class LOI(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    poi = models.ManyToManyField(POI)
    LOI_title = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    loi_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

**Form.py**

```
 class LOIForm(forms.ModelForm):
 class Meta:
    model = models.LOI
    fields = ['poi','LOI_title']
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LOIForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['poi'].widget = forms.widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
        self.fields['LOI_title'].label= 'title'
```

**Views.py**

```
 if request.method == 'POST':
    request.POST.get("name", request.user.username)
    loi_form = forms.LOIForm(request.POST)
    if loi_form.is_valid():
        loi_form = loi_form.save(commit=False)
        loi_form.user = request.user
        loi_form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/make_LOI')
```

**template**

```
<table>
   {% for p in loi_form.poi %}
       <tr>{{p}}</tr>
   {% endfor%}
</table>
```

Comment: u need to explain the question more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are using `commit=False` in `form.save()`. In that case, after `loi_form.save()` you will need to add `loi_form.save_m2m()` to save many-to-many fields.
2. In `__unicode__` function you are returning `self.POI_date, self.user` which shows the result as in image. Instead use:

   ```
   def __str__(self):
       return self.POI_title
   ```

`__unicode__` was used in python2, using just `__str__` will be enough. Remove `__unicode__` function.

Comment: By the way, why `self.fields['poi'].widget = forms.widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple()` didn't chande to checkbox from origin image?

Comment: First of all, where you make this change? It needs to be done in `__init__` function of the Form, or directly inside form items (before `class Meta`). Also just writing `forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()` will be enough, no need for `forms.widgets`.

Comment: Also you wrote `__init__` function inside Meta, that is incorrect. It should be inside `LOIForm` (same line as `class Meta:`)